# Heroku Procfile increases slug size dramatically

Tags: heroku, playframework

I have a scala + play (2.3) app, which I deploy on heroku. When there is no Procfile defined, the app deploys and runs without any problems (heroku detects that this is a scala play application). The slug size is 89MB

However, when I add a very simple Procfile:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/app_name -Dconfig.resource=application-heroku.conf
```

where `application-heroku.conf` is just a copy of my `application.conf` (I wanted to create separate `application.conf`s for dev and prod)

the slug size increases to 380MB and the application fails to deploy (as the limit is 300MB).
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Something is preventing the buildpack from clearing out the build artifacts before preparing the slug. Do you see these lines in your build output:

```
-----> Dropping ivy cache from the slug
-----> Dropping sbt boot dir from the slug
-----> Dropping project boot dir from the slug
-----> Dropping compilation artifacts from the slug
```

If not, can you confirm that either

- You have a `conf/application.conf` file in your project (even if you don't use it)
- Or you have the `sbt-native-packager` dependency in your `project/plugins.sbt`

If neither of these is true, the buildpack cannot safe clear the build artifacts. If you do not have a `conf/application.conf` try adding one -- even if it's an empty place holder.

If you *do* see those "Dropping" lines in your build output, and are still getting a slug that is too big, then check that you are not using a custom buildpack (i.e. that your BUILDPACK_URL is not set).

Comment: Same issue as @jfu with play 2.2.6. No dropping lines. Added a default application.conf as joekutner suggested and it worked like a charm. But why does it need the default application.conf?